# CSS &::before { not working

Tags: css, ionic2

I am using Ionic2 and trying to apply a style. I have a message box:

[image]

and am trying to apply this image to it:

[image]

so that it looks like it is joined to the message box.

My problem is that the image is not applied at all.

I have the following css. As you can see the image is defined here: `background-image: url(/assets/message-you.png)`. The image exists in that location, because if I hover over the it in Firebug for example, the image is there.

I got this css from a tutorial and am not sure how `&::before {` works.

Any advise appreciated.

```
.messages-page-content {
  > scroll-content {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .messages {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #E0DAD6;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .message-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 9px;

    &::after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
  }

  .message {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 236px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);

    &.message-me {
      float: right;
      background-color: #DCF8C6;

      &::before {
        right: -11px;
        background-image: url(/assets/message-me.png)
      }
    }

    &.message-you {
      float: left;
      background-color: #FFF;

      &::before {
        left: -11px;
        background-image: url(/assets/message-you.png)
      }
    }

    &.message-you::before, &.message-me::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 3px;
      width: 12px;
      height: 19px;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
    }

    .message-content {
      padding: 5px 7px;
      word-wrap: break-word;

      &::after {
        content: " \00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0";
        display: inline;
      }
    }

    .message-timestamp {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 2px;
      right: 17px;
      font-size: 11px;
      color: gray;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the console output:

[image]

As you can see in Firebug, the image exists:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `content:"";` to your `::before`-elements.

EDIT:

I saw you already had content:""; on your before-elements..

Comment: Hi rblarsen, thanks for your feedback. I apologize that my css knowledge is so limited, but I don't really understand, can you expand your description and possibly give an example.

Comment: I just saw you already had content:""; on your before-elements.. Have you tried closing the lines with the background-image? `background-image: url(/assets/message-me.png);`

Comment: If you mean doing this? `content: url(/assets/message-you.png);`, it makes no difference.